# Object property referenced within the same object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS object as follows:

```
var actType = {
    form  : $form,
    input : "select[name='journalEntry.activityType']",
    valid : $form.find("select[name='journalEntry.activityType']").val() === "",
    errorClass: "sr-error-task",
    errorMessage: "Please select a task."
};
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to reference the $form value in the actType.valid parameter with actType.form?
2. Would the first actType.form = "test" and the second actType = "pass" considering this code?

For example:

```
$form = "test";
var actType = {
    form  : $form,
    input : "select[name='journalEntry.activityType']",
    valid : $form.find("select[name='journalEntry.activityType']").val() === "",
    errorClass: "sr-error-task",
    errorMessage: "Please select a task."
};

$form = "pass";
actType = {
    form  : $form,
    input : "select[name='journalEntry.activityType']",
    valid : $form.find("select[name='journalEntry.activityType']").val() === "",
    errorClass: "sr-error-task",
    errorMessage: "Please select a task."
};
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but you're making `$form` a string, then you're referencing it as a string, then as a jQuery object?

Comment: To correct your terminology, this question has nothing to do with JSON (JavaScript Object **Notation**). You have a JavaScript **object**. JSON refers to a string with formatting the same as JavaScript Object declaration syntax.

Comment: 1) No, actType is undefined until the statement is completed, so actType.form will be an access error. 2) Yes, standard JavaScript.

Comment: @Travesty3, I think this question is relevant to JSON as he is asking what values the resultant object takes on with different JSON formulations.

Comment: this is a js object...

Comment: @StephenChung: There's no JSON here. It's a JS object.

Comment: @StephenChung—there is no JSON here. According to ECMA-262 what he OP has is an [object initializer](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5), also known as an object literal (though it is strictly not a [literal according to the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8)).

Comment: Doh! You're right. It is an object initializer, not JSON. Although the syntax is similar (as JSON is based on JS's object initializer syntax)